# Switch between webview and native activities

Tags: android, webview

I am learning android apps (thru studio) and had a basic query. Is it possible to switch between a `webview` activity and a `native` active in android.

Basically if I click a button in my `webview`, it will take me to a page in my `native` code. And if I click a button in that `native` page, it will take me back to my `webview` (I am agnostic if my state of webview changes or not).

Any guidance will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, check [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) on details